# Doxygen doesn't generate References function call relation for class method whose object created indirectly

Tags: doxygen

References to `Array<>::print` is missing for `testTemplate` in document generated for below example documentation:

[image: doc].

```
#include"lib.h"
using namespace std;
void testTemplate(void);
int main()
{
    testTemplate();
    return 0;
}

void testTemplate(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    using array_type = Array<int>;
    array_type array2(arr, 5);
    array2.print();
}

#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    T *ptr;
    int size;
public:
    Array(T arr[], int s);
    void print();
};

template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(T arr[], int s)
{
    ptr = new T[s];
    size = s;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = arr[i];
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<" "<<*(ptr + i);
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Doxygen settings:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
RESOLVE_UNNAMED_PARAMS = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
```

***Exmaple 2: similar use case***

file <project_name.h>

```
class ProjectName
{
public:
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Array<int> array_type;

    ProjectName(void):array_type(arr,5)
    {
    }

    void print(void)
    {
        std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
    }
};

ProjectName& getProjectName(void);
```

file <project_name.cpp>

```
#include "project_name.h"

ProjectName& getProjectName(void)
{
    static ProjectName obj;
    return obj;
}
```

file <main.cpp>

```
#include <iostream>
#include"project_name.h"

using namespace std;

void testTemplate(void);

int main()
{
    testTemplate();
    return 0;
}

void testTemplate(void)
{
    ProjectName& project = getProjectName();
    project.print();
    project.array_type.print();
}
```

References to `Array<>::print` is missing for `testTemplate` in generated document [image]:

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: Doxygen version 1.9.2

Comment: Problem here is that doxygen is not good in using the `using` statement. When using `Array<int> c(arr,5)` and `c.print()` the reference is shown. Note I think that you missed in your settings in the issue here `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES` and `REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES`.

Comment: I had set 'REFERENCES_RELATION = YES' and 'REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES'